# Access specifiers and code-reusability in java

Tags: java

How does the access specifiers like private, public, etc. help in code re-usability?

i got this question for an interview and i were not able to find the ans. plz help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several fine lines around this, with which I could answer the question a few different ways.

Consider the case where a developer marks just about everything as private.  It may have been a perfectly good class that could have been reused if only I could have extended it and overridden the `doSomething()` method. However, since the method has been marked private, my hands are tied.  This will cause many developers to copy & paste the entire class, changing the one necessary part.  (Not cool.)  So it could be seen that marking everything as private prevents reuse.

However, on the other hand, consider the case where a developer marks everything as public.  That developer or other developers start writing extension classes, or calling all of the various methods / accessing attributes which maybe should have been marked protected / private.  A design bug or such is found, which requires the class to be modified.  However, since it was written so "open", what may have been a simple fix is now much more complex, as all of the additional references have to be found and considered.

I think the best option is a compromise.  Mark things that are designed to be used by client code as "public".  Mark things that have no business being extended / overridden as "private".  If there is something that could prove useful to someone in the future to extend, mark it as "protected".  And always add Javadocs to further signal your intentions.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. But im want the ans for how these access modifiers are helping the code-re usability.

Answer (score 1):

Code that is to be reused needs to be understandable and reliable.

Understandable: By making some methods private the author of a class specifies that those methods are internal implementation deatils, the re-user needs only consider the public methods.

Reliable: By making fields private we prevent the re-user accidentally corrupting the internal state of the reused code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are well aware of the scope of these access specifiers such as

**private-class only**

**default-package only**

**protected-class and derived classes**

**public- all**

Now imagine you have a class that contains a method

```
public int calculate(int x,int y,int z){
z=x+y;
x=z+x;
z=x+y;
return z;
}
```

This is a public method and can accesed from anywhere,any package and any class whether it is derived or not.
Now you want to use this function in a new class, you can simply import this class and use the method without writing it again and again.

This is a very simple example,you can replace with your own function here such as checking the series is a fibonacci series or not,calculating simple interest/compund interest etc.. and reuse it wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a utility helper class that I want someone else to be able to re-use. I have loads of methods and variables in that class, but people using that class don't need them.

- `public` marks the method that can be easily re-used. It should always be well documented so that someone knows how and when to call it.
- `private` marks the member as part of the internal mechanism - my re-users don't need to worry about it.

By being explicit about the access model allowed you make it more clear about how that code should be accessed, and hence make it more maintainable and easier for others to re-use.

In an interview (and I've hired quite a few developers) you should be able to clearly explain the purpose of every access modifier and be able to give an example of each's usage.